# Primes p dividing $10^\frac{p-1}{3}-1$

Tags: number-theory

The primes $73$, $12763$ and $255127$, formed by the concatenation of two consecutive Mersenne numbers, have this property:

$73$ divides $10^\frac{73-1}{3}-1$

$12763$ divides $10^\frac{12763-1}{3}-1$

$255127$ divides $10^\frac{255127-1}{3}-1$

I wonder if there are other primes p which divide $10^\frac{p-1}{3}-1$ and in particular if there are other primes formed by the concatenation of two consecutive Mersenne numbers with that property.

Comment: $p$ divides $10^{(p-1)/3}-1$ if and only if $10$ is a cubic residue modulo $p$.